# After running yarn run watch:venia the command run successfully and got the build url but getting error response as mentioned below:

Tags: magento2, pwa-studio, venia

**i have set the urls as:**

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="http://magentovenia.com/"
MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_EXACT_DOMAIN='pwa.magentovenia.com'
```

**But Getting Error Response In Browser**

> message   "Error: ServiceResolver: Request to
>   http://magentovenia.com/graphql failed: ServerParseError: Unexpected
>   token < in JSON at position 8\n    at makePromise.then.catch.e
>   (/var/www/html/magento/pwa-studio/packages/upward-js/lib/resolvers/ServiceResolver.js:105:23)\n
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"

Answer (score 1):

**Hello SRG**

Please check you backend url configuration.
Go to packages/venia-concept/.env
Open this file and check MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL url

For my case it was

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="http://127.0.0.1/magento2.3.1"
```

Add slash "/" at the end of url

```
 MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="http://127.0.0.1/magento2.3.1/"
```

It should be work.

May be it will help you.

Comment: I have already restarted the server but still issue not resolved.

Comment: Hello @srg please check now it should be work. I have edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

did you check whether your magento was installed properly, i mean are you able to go on your magento website ? 
In my case i was not be able to reach my magento website set on my local. After fix that problem, I just ran again the yarn command and it worked